# can't get length of string array

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting output in string format then I split it and want to do further processing, here is my code snippet,

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()){

String[] splitLine = str.split("~");

String splitData[];
    int i=0;
    for( i=0;i<splitLine.length;i++){

        splitData = splitLine[i].split("#");

        if(Long.parseLong(splitData[0]) == oid)
            isParent = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

But, the problem is that I am unable to get length of **`splitLine` String array** and also eclipse shows a warning as a **dead code** for `i++` inside for loop, I am cant able to understand why this happen does anybody have idea about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `break` is the problem. It belongs to the preceeding `if` but that has no curly braces. Change it to this:

```
if(Long.parseLong(splitData[0]) == oid) {
    isParent = true;
    break;
}
```